Trouble with the concept of external force on a system

In the diagram above, there is no frictional force on $m_1$, the rope and the pulley are massless. There is earth gravity.
We find that the horizontal component of the acceleration of the center of mass of the system composed of $m_1$ and $m_2$, is $\large\frac{m_1m_2g}{(m_1+m_2)^2}$, and that the vertical component is $\large\frac{-m_2m_2g}{(m_1+m_2)^2}$.
However, we learn that $a_{\text{com}} = \large\frac{F_{\text{net}}}{\text{mass}}$ where $F_{\text{net}}$ is the vector sum of all external forces. But here, it seems that the only external force is gravity on $m_2$ which is $-m_2g$ so that would mean $a_{\text{com}}$ only has a vertical component: $\large\frac{-m_2g}{(m_1+m_2)}$. This is not what is found.
Since the equation $a_{\text{com}}=\large\frac{F_{\text{net}}}{\text{mass}}$ must be correct, it seems that I don't understand the concept of external forces on a system well.
Could you explain what are the other external forces in this system? The question is not about how to find the result and solve the problem, but about the concept of external forces acting on this system.

Gravity is not the only force acting on the masses and the rope, there is also the force due to pulley on the rope.

"the only external force is gravity on m2" What about the normal force on $m_1$?

The force due to pulley on the rope is internal. I forgot normal force but it is cancelled by gravity on m1 anyways.

Okay, but the pulley is being held up by the ground. A normal upwards force is being applied on the pulley to counteract the downwards force of $m_2$.

By the way, did you make a typo in the formula for the vertical component of acceleration? $-m_2m_2$ doesn't make much sense to me.

The force from the pulley on the rope is not an internal force

@Dale  Could we define the pulley to be part of the system, hence its force to be internal?

There are many ways to show that there is another external force acting on the two mass and string system other than the two gravitational forces on the masses and the normal force on mass $m_1$, the resultant of those being a vertical force down of $m_2g$.
One way is to note that the centre of mass of the system has a horizontal acceleration as well as a vertical acceleration supposedly under the action of a vertical force.
Another way is to consider the massless string as a system with a horizontal force on it due to one mass and a vertical force on it due to the other mass.
If they were the only two forces then there would be a net force on the massless string which is impossible, thus there must be a force on the string due to the pulley to make the net force on the string zero.
If they were the only forces acting on

"One way is to note that the centre of mass of the system has a horizontal acceleration..." OP has acknowledge that but is asking what is the external force that is causing the CM of the system to accelerate horizontally.

It is the force on the string due to the pulley.

What if we consider the pulley to be part of the system?

Then you change the position of the centre of mass of the system and now there is an external force on the pulley due to the object it is connected to.

The pulley is stipulated to be massless so including it in the system should not change the center of mass of the system. What if we include in the system the object it's connect to? Then wouldn't the only force on that system be gravity, in the vertical direction?

So now the gravitational forces are internal forces and the system has no external forces acting on it.

I wasn't including the Earth, just the rail that the pulley is attached to, so gravity is an external force but only in the vertical direction. But even assuming your scenario that the system has no external forces acting on it, then the momentum in the horizontal direction should not change. I don't know why this is giving me such trouble.

The horizontal movement to the right of truck $m_1$ will be compensate for by the horizontal movement to the left of the pulley, table, Earth, etc.

Ah, now It's starting to make more sense, but I'll have to ponder it a bit more.
